# Installing headers in subdirectories with (nobase_)pkginclude_HEADERS

Tags: c++, autotools, automake

I have a little problem with automake to handle the subdirectories when installing headers.

Here is roughly the project hierarchy that I have:

```
foo/
  foo-bin/
    Makefile.am
    ...
  foo-tests/
    Makefile.am
    ...
  foo-lib/
    Makefile.am
    include/
      foo/
        header1.h
        subdir/
          header2.h
    src/
      file1.cpp
```

Nothing too fancy, there is a root directory containing the `configure.ac`, and 3 subdirectories for the shared library, the main binary, and the tests.

The interesting part here is `foo-lib/`. It contains the library that the binary and tests link to.

Since I want to be able to generate the configure files out of the source tree, I've settled to use `$top_srcdir`-relative path in my `Makefile.am`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
  $(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/src/file1.cpp

pkginclude_HEADERS = \
  $(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/header1.h \
  $(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/subdir/header2.h
```

Without these `$top_srcdir`-relative path, I have problems when I try to use the `foo-lib` from `foo-bin`, or when I try to generate the project out of the source tree.

Now the problem: when installing these headers, they end up being flattened!
That is, I end up with:

```
$prefix/include/foo/header1.h
$prefix/include/foo/header2.h
```

While I was expecting:

```
$prefix/include/foo/header1.h
$prefix/include/foo/subdir/header2.h
```

So I assume that is what `nobase_` is supposed to achieve, but since the path I use are not relative to the `Makefile.am`, but to `$top_srcdir`, I end up with the whole `$top_srcdir` path being copied:

```
$prefix/include/foo-lib/include/foo/header1.h
$prefix/include/foo-lib/include/foo/subdir/header2.h
```

which is clearly not what is expected.

Any thoughts and advises on this are greatly appreciated :)
If you need access to the real `Makefile.am` files, instead of the canonical examples, the project is here:

https://github.com/NewbiZ/crashburn

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your decision to use a `$top_srcdir`-relative path in your Makefile.am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
pkginclude_HEADERS = \
$(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/header1.h \
$(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/subdir/header2.h
```

tells the install to place the headers above in `$(pkgincludedir)`, so flattened is how you told them to be.

What you could do is:

```
myincludesubdir=$(pkgincludedir)/subdir

pkginclude_HEADERS = $(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/header1.h
myincludesub_HEADERS = $(top_srcdir)/foo-lib/include/foo/subdir/header2.h
```

This should install `header1.h` to `$(pkgincludedir)` and `header2.h` to `$(myincludesubdir)` aka `$(pkgincludedir)/subdir`.

I wouldn't use `nobase_` in this case. The results you got using it don't look unexpected or erroneous to me.